# If the Rose Bomb is so powerful and poisonous, why didn't the hunter association airdrop a dozen on the palace when fighting against the ants?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In *Hunter x Hunter*, why didn't the hunter association airdrop a dozen of Rose Bomb on the palace and called it a day when fighting against the ants?

The could have used the teleportation guy to drop a couple dozen of those roses and *boom*, they're all dead. And even if they're not, there's poison to finish them off. That would've been so much easier than fighting them.

Also, it's not farfetched to assume that the hunter association has a special distress signal to contact Ging. Call Ging. He snaps his fingers and *bam*, all the ants drop dead.

Comment: I believe there were civilians in and around the palace(?) Idk about Ging.

Comment: Um how does Ging "snapping his finger", kill all the ants? I'm a bit lost on that part

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin AFAIK, it's an indirect way of saying that someone is powerful enough to have been able to do something, like a figure of speech that should not be taken literally. Now that OP mentions it, it's curious what Ging was doing during this time (no mention in the manga, if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Netero wanted to settle the matter as a Hunter first, but implanted the bomb within himself as a contingency plan. He went in personally and fought Meruem. He lured Meruem away and fought him solo in the desert, when it was clear that he could not win, he killed himself, triggering the bomb a safe distance away from any casualties.

Also, HxH is a shounen series and they had to settle it the shounen way, with a 1v1 fight.

Answer (score 0):

They probably didn't want to bomb the entire palace since there were innocent civilians who'd get caught in the crossfire. They also did believe that Pitou could reverse he nen hold on Kite, and wanted Gon to settle things his way as far as that was concerned. Netero is also a martial artist who wanted to push himself to his limit and find out how strong Meruem truly was which maybe why he only wanted a 1v1 with Meruem, probably also why he only took Zeno's help in separating the ant king and not in killing him(Zeno would've rejected that request anyways cause the Zoldycks are a smart bunch, relatively).

There's also a lot of inconsistency in the series to be fair, I mean, Meruem could have easily guarded himself against the impact of the bomb had he used his nen. He's literally the strongest creature on that land. He could've also negated the effect of the poison when he realized it but they had to kill him or Netero and everyone else present there would've deid in vain.

But as the other answer states, it is a shounen series and they had to settle it in the old fashioned way. As to why Ging or anyone else wasn't called, it was probably the only way the author could've extended the series. Almost all of the last part with the new chairman election and Gon's condition would've been completely removed from the series.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished watching the fight between Netero and Meruem. I think the guys on the phone with Netero threatened to sacrifice as many people as possible if he didn’t accept to carry the bomb within himself. That way, they could put the blame on the Hunter Association if any problem were to be faced.

Why Netero? He is the Hunter Association’s president, and people would think he is the most powerful hunter. If it were to be discovered that they used radioactivity, all that would have to be said is that they didn’t have a choice...

Before dying, Netero told Meruem that there were no limits to human’s evilness